# не загружается explorer.exe windows 7

Tags: windows-7

При загрузке компьютера explorer не стартует автоматически, его приходится каждый раз загружать вручную через Диспетчер задач. Причем такое наблюдается и при загрузке в безопасном режиме.

Пробовала после нажатия F8 выбирать пункт `"Устранение неполадок"`, но после выбора появилась ошибка:

> "0xc000000f The boot selection failed because a required device is
>   inaccessible."

На ноуте стоит Windows 7 basic x64, найти какой-нибудь рабочий образ, чтобы загрузить восстановление с него - тоже не получается, выводит ошибку о несовместимости версий.

Практически на всех форумах, при возникновении такой ошибки советуется проверить реестр, а точнее убедиться, что в `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` в переменной `Shell` находится только `explorer.exe` и удалить  `explorer.exe`  и `iexplorer.exe` в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\.`

Ничто из этого не сработало.Проверка AVZ тоже не помогла... Если Вы сталкивались с подобной проблемой, подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее решить?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Comment: [SharpE или прочие альтернативные explorer.exe оболочки](http://www.ixbt.com/soft/winshells.shtml) не хотели бы попробовать?

Comment: Спасибо))) честно говоря, я о них даже не подумала)

Answer (score 2):

могу предложить 2 варинанта:
1. Добавить его в автозагрузку
2. C установочного диска скопировать и заменить ваш explorer.exe

[manual](http://remontcompa.ru/291-explorerexe-oshibka-prilozheniya.html)

Comment: спасибо) первый вариант я попробовала в первую очередь )

Comment: насчет второго есть небольшие сомнения.... ведь если бы был поврежден конкретно explorer.exe  то его нельзя было бы запустить через Диспетчер задач или я что-то не понимаю? В любом случае спасибо вам за идею) Сегодня обязательно опробую)